# passing variables between views in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an index view file that displays the list of events.

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to event.title, show_event_path(event) %></td>
    <td><%= event.date %></td>
    <td><%= event.location %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I want to display that event in another view file.

```
<h1 id="event_title"><%= @event.title %></h1>
<p><%= @event.description %></p>
<p>Date: <%= @event.date %></p>
<p>Location:<%= @event.location %></p>
```

How do I pass that event variable to another view file??

Answer (score 0):

You don't "pass the variable to the other view file". Your link is calling another action with an event ID, and in that action you would load the Event record, and pass it to the view for displaying.